# Regex for different classname form input

Tags: regex, validation, classname

This is the original code

```
  $('.holder').on('keypress', 'alphabet', function (e) {
        if (window.event) code = e.keyCode;
        else code = e.which;
        var myRegExp = new RegeExp(/[A-Z]/i);
        if (myRegExp.test(String.fromCharCode(code))) {
            return true;
        } else return false;
    });
```

however i want to make this code reusable as classname as parameter, like this one, but its not working :

```
  $('.holder').on('keypress', classname, function (e) {
      if (window.event) code = e.keyCode;
      else code = e.which;
      var pattern;
      if (classname == "alphabet") pattern = /[A-Z]/i;
      else if (classname == "number") pattern = /[0-9]/;
      var myRegExp = new RegeExp(pattern);
      if (myRegExp.test(String.fromCharCode(code))) {
          return true;
      } else return false;
  });
```

see this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/1Luwpvok/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be your HTML. You should have a `name` attribute for an `input` element

```
<div class="holder">
    alphabets only : <input type="text" name="name" class="alphabet" /><br />
    numbers only : <input type="text" name="age" class="number" />
</div>
```

And this is the JavaScript. You need an event on `input` and not on `holder` and you don't need to pass `classname` as a parameter; rather check it with `.attr('class')`

```
$('input').on('keypress', function (e) {
      if (window.event) code = e.keyCode;
      else code = e.which;
      var pattern;
      if ($(this).attr('class') == "alphabet") pattern = /[A-Z]/i;
      else if ($(this).attr('class') == "number") pattern = /[0-9]/;
      var myRegExp = new RegExp(pattern);
      if (myRegExp.test(String.fromCharCode(code))) {
          return true;
      } else return false;
  });
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/1Luwpvok/3/)

Answer (score 1):

`on(...)` does not define a function. It *calls* a function. You can't have an undefined variable there. Wrap the whole thing into a function.

Also, the second parameter to `on(...)` needs to be a selector, but `"alphabet"` would try to select a tag `<alphabet>`, which does not exist. The class selector is `".alphabet"`.

You also misspelled RegExp.

```
function applyKeypressValidation(selector, classname) {
  $('.holder').on('keypress', selector, function (e) {
      if (window.event) code = e.keyCode;
      else code = e.which;
      var pattern;
      if (classname == "alphabet") pattern = /[A-Z]/i;
      else if (classname == "number") pattern = /[0-9]/;
      var myRegExp = new RegExp(pattern);
      if (myRegExp.test(String.fromCharCode(code))) {
          return true;
      } else return false;
  });
}

applyKeypressValidation('.alphabet', 'alphabet');
applyKeypressValidation('.number', 'number');
```

Comment: can i go like this? your answer give me correct output but is there  a way i can use like this `$('.holder').on('keypress',  function (e,var classname)` @Amadan

Comment: No. The signature of the function that `on(...)` accepts is determined by `on(...)`, you can't just randomly change it.